# SetSystemCursor not animating *.ani cursors

Tags: c, winapi

I have just about exhausted every link on Google and SO without finding a solution... This may be a duplicate, but the other questions either aren't answered or weren't helpful and are years old. For some reason nothing works for me.

In my program I need to change the system-wide cursor to a different cursor depending on the active feature. The program adds and extends features of the mouse, and changing the cursor will be the indicator of the active feature. The user will opt-in for this feature, knowing the cursor will change.

The problem now is that using SetSystemCursor doesn't seem to animate, but instead just draws the first frame of the animation. I noticed that by using SetCursor the animations work, but only within the application itself (which is only used for settings. It also doesn't preserve the cursor type (arrow, text, link...)). Why doesn't SetSytemCursor work, and is there a way to get it to work?

---

---

Examples of what I have tried so far... They all work to the extent that they draw the first frame of the animation, none actually animates. Using SetCursor instead will produce an animating cursor, but not system-wide specific cursors as needed. The Set* functions return successfully.

1: Simple attempt to set a cursor

```
SetSystemCursor( LoadCursorFromFile( L"custom_cursor.ani" ), OCR_NORMAL );
```

---

2: My attempt, using what was written in docs

```
/* Global HCURSOR */ arrowCurs = LoadCursorFromFile( L"custom_cursor.ani" );
HCURSOR temp = ( HCURSOR )CopyImage( arrowCurs, IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, 0 );
SetSystemCursor( temp, OCR_NORMAL );
DestroyCursor( temp );
```

---

3: This is from an SO answer that I found, link lost

```
FILE* fs = fopen( "--full path--\\custom_cursor.ani", "rb" );
fseek( fs, 0, SEEK_END ); int dwSize = ftell( fs ); fseek( fs, 0, SEEK_SET );
char* memory = new char[ dwSize + guardbandSize ];
fread( memory, 1, dwSize, fs ); memset( memory + dwSize, 0, guardbandSize );
fclose( fs );
SetSystemCursor( ( HCURSOR )CreateIconFromResource( ( PBYTE )memory, dwSize, FALSE, 0x00030000 ), 32512 );
delete memory;
```

---

---

The only solution so far is to not change the cursor icon, but instead hide it and draw a borderless top-most window with the animation drawn on it. However I would like to leave that as a last option, if using SetSystemCursor is not possible, due to the added complexity and inelegance.

Using Windows 10 x64 and Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I don't think `SetSystemCursor` supports animated cursors. You can write the new filename to the appropriate value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors` and then use `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS...);` to make the system reload the cursors.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for the tip, I'll look into that. I still don't get why animated cursors wouldn't work, especially given that Microsoft's own documents include remarks about using .ani cursors. I think it has to do with the automatic destroying of the cursor, but again, doesn't make sense why they would disallow .ani cursors. Also, it sounds like people online have previously gotten them to work...

Comment: I consider this broken/a bug in Windows 10... SetSystemCursor used to work fine with .ani animated cursors in Windows 7 and XP, agreeing with their own documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A better solution is still appreciated.**

Based on the comment from Potter and my own experience; it appears that you cannot set .ani cursors with SetSystemCursor -- this solution will successfully change the cursor to an animation cursor, however it requires admin privileges, and note that it will permanently set the cursor for the given user, unlike SetSystemCursor which is temporary until session restart.

```
HKEY key;
// The location of the new cursor to be set:
LPCWSTR loc = L"C:\\--full path--\\custom_cursor.ani";

if ( ERROR_SUCCESS == RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Control Panel\\Cursors", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &key ) &&
     ERROR_SUCCESS == RegSetValueEx( key, L"Arrow", 0, REG_EXPAND_SZ, ( LPBYTE )loc, wcslen( loc ) * sizeof(  WCHAR ) ) )
{
    RegCloseKey(key);
}
else
{
    // Print error if failed
    WCHAR msg[ 256 ];
    FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, 0, 0, msg, 256, 0 );
    OutputDebugString( msg );
}

SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, NULL, 0 ); // Reload system cursors
```

Change L"Arrow" to any other cursor type respectively to change it's icon.

It's also worth to store the original registry values externally and implement a method to reset on exit or in case of a crash.